# How to run svn-populate-node-origins-index on Windows

Tags: svn

I am about to update our SVN repository, and I need to run this script after: svn-populate-node-origins-index

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/server-side/svn-populate-node-origins-index.c

How can I run it on my Windows 2003 Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tool is now provided with new installations as an executable file. Simply run:

C:\Program Files\CollabNet Subversion Server>svn-populate-node-origins-index.exe [YOUR_REPOSITORY]